# SQL to group a similar table by name

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two similar tables

**Table 1**

```
  | id | name | amount|
  | 2  | Mike | 1000  |
  | 3  | Dave | 2500  |
```

**Table 2**

```
  | id | name | amount|
  | 2  | Mike | 1200  |
  | 4  | James| 2500  |
```

I want to query the tables to get a result like this:

```
  | id | name | amount_table1| amount_table2|
  | 2  | Mike | 1000         | 1200         |
  | 3  | Dave | 2500         |              |
  | 4  | james|              | 2500         |
```

Comment: Why do you have two tables for the same data? Why have you tagged MySql & SQL Server? Which one is it? Please also share your query

Comment: What's the expected result if you add (5, Mike, 2000) to table1?

Comment: @Raj sorry its MySQL. the two tables are similar but not the same, but i need to display a comprehensive results for each user from the two tables

Comment: @Raj i am not trying to create another table in the database,  i want to display on the website a table showing a comprehensive data from the two tables

Answer (score 2):

`UNION ALL` the tables. Do `GROUP BY` to get one row per id/name combo.

```
select id, name, sum(amount1), sum(amount2)
from
(
    select id, name, amount as amount1, null as amount2 from table1
    union all
    select id, name, null, amount  from table2
) dt
group by id, name
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do union with left and right join

```
select a.id , a.name , a.amount amount_table1,b.amount amount_table2 from table1 a left join table2 b on (a.id=b.id)
union
select b.id , b.name ,a.amount,b.amount from table1 a right join table2 b on (a.id=b.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

MySql doesn't support FULL OUTER JOIN.
But it supports LEFT & RIGHT joins and UNION.

```
select 
t1.id, t1.name, t1.amount as amount_table1, t2.amount as amount_table2
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id

union all

select t2.id, t2.name, t1.amount, t2.amount
from Table2 t2
left join Table1 t1 on t2.id = t1.id
where t1.id is null
```

The first select will get those only in Table1 and those in both.
The second select will get those only in Table2.
And the UNION glues those resultsets together.

If this were for a database that supports FULL JOIN then it would be simplified to:

```
select 
coalesce(t1.id, t2.id) as id, 
coalesce(t1.name, t2.name) as name, 
t1.amount as amount_table1, 
t2.amount as amount_table2
from Table1 t1
full join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```